# Importing a list of references into LyX

Tags: jabref, lyx-layouts

I have a JabRef reference list and like to import the list elements into LyX to create a LyX file with the actual list of references. I cannot do it. Any idea how to do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Note: I currently only have access to an old version of LyX (2.1.2), things may be different in the current 2.3 version.</sub>

A bit of background first. The way LaTeX and BibTeX makes the bibliography is that BibTeX creates a `.bbl` file that has LaTeX code for generating a list of references. This is based on the citations in your document, and the information on the `.bib` file. So if you want to make the document self-contained, i.e. not depend on the `.bib` file, you need to get the information in the `.bbl` file generated by BibTeX, and copy-paste that into the LaTeX document.

With LyX this becomes marginally more complicated, as the LaTeX file and `.bbl` file are generated in a temporary folder. But step by step the process would be something like this:

- Have the document open in LyX, and the PDF generated. (I don't know when the temporary files disappear, but if you've just generated the PDF, they will surely be there.)
- To work out where LyX saves the temporary files, go to Tools --> Preferences -> Paths, and see what path is given in the *Temporary directory* field. On my system it's `/tmp`.
- Go to that folder (`/tmp`, or whatever it was). Here you'll probably find a subfolder named something with `lyx`, and inside this one or more additional subfolders. There might be one for every document, I don't really know. Find the subfolder containing the latest version of your paper, by looking at the name and/or modification date of the files, or by looking at the PDF itself (which will be in that deepest subfolder).
- Find the file in that folder with the extension `.bbl`, and open it in a text editor.
- Select all, and copy.
- Go back to LyX.
- Either delete the current BibTeX bibliography inset that you have, or move it into a LyX note (Insert --> Note --> LyX note).
- Add an ERT with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> or Insert -> TeX Code.
- Paste the text from the `.bbl` file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>. (Mind the <kbd>Shift</kbd>, without it linebreaks is ignored, usually.)

## Original answer

JabRef creates a `.bib` file. In order to use such a bibliography database in a document the basic steps are as follows:

- Insert --> List/ToC --> BibTeX bibliography.
- Click Add, and find your `.bib` file.
- Choose an appropriate style.
- If you want *all* the entries in that `.bib` file to show up in the reference list, choose *all references* from the *Content* drop down (instead of the *all cited references* which is the default).
- Click OK.

Depending on choice of style you may need to change some settings in Document --> Settings --> Bibliography, but you haven't said anything about what kind of style you'd like to have.

Comment: I can already get the JabRef reference list inside LyX. I have no problem with that. My question was not clear maybe: I want to have the reference list inside LyX as a simple text because the journal my article will be published wants the reference list inside the LyX, not retrieve it from JebRef inside LyX. The style is APA.

Comment: @TugrulTemel I think I see, that was impossible for me to understand from the way you phrased the question. You need to find the temporary `.bbl` file generated by LyX and copy-paste the contents of that into an ERT, will edit in a bit.

Comment: Thank you. I will try your proposal and see how it goes. I hope it will work out. I will inform you on the output.

Comment: @TugrulTemel Just updated the answer.

Comment: It did not work in the way I wanted. Here is why. In the original case, my LyX manuscript is linked to JabRef references in APA style, and bibliography list generated in the LyX manuscript is linked to the specific citations made in the manuscript. With your proposal, I loose all the links between the citations and bibliographies. That is a big problem for me because my reference list is too long and I do not want to loose the link. Do you have any idea about not loosing the link?

Comment: @TugrulTemel what exactly do you mean by link?

Comment: With link, I mean that BibTeX generated Bibliography establishes a link between a "JebRef" reference item and the actual citation of that reference in the LyX manuscript. For example, if there is a paper by Temel (2002) listed in the JebRef reference, and if it is cited in the LyX manuscript, then (Temel, 2002) will automatically be shown in the manuscript in the place where it is cited. With your method, all of the citations have `(???)` in place of citations.

Comment: I forgot to put the `copy` and `paste` list into in ERT. I did now use ERT but then several errors are coming out, which I do not understand at all.

Comment: @TugrulTemel For me it works fine, no errors. However, I can't possibly guess what's wrong without knowing which errors you get.

Comment: Here is the Error coming out: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6800 64-bit) entering extended mode C:/Users/ttemel/Documents/Temp/lyx_tmpdir.gq4628/lyx_tmpbuf2/ESWA_12313_expert
_knowledge_TTEMEL_rv2_7nov18.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed.
The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\ttemel\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\texify.log`

Comment: @TugrulTemel Haven't got the faintest idea what causes that. If something banal as restarting LyX doesn't fix it, I'd suggest asking a new question.

Comment: @Tornbjorn: Thank you so much for your help. I will try to prepare a new question to solve this problem.